iptables forgets states after losing carrier
I have an issue with linux firewall, looks like it forgets states right after physical connection goes down.
There is an established ssh session, but firewall starts dropping packets after connection recovers.  Here is a piece of log:
Aug 09 21:39:12 systemd-networkd[615]: re0: Lost carrier
Aug 09 21:39:12 systemd-networkd[615]: re0: DHCP lease lost
Aug 09 21:39:12 systemd-timesyncd[565]: No network connectivity, watching for changes.
Aug 09 21:39:12 systemd[1]: Starting resolvconf-pull-resolved.service...
Aug 09 21:39:12 systemd[1]: resolvconf-pull-resolved.service: Deactivated successfully.
Aug 09 21:39:12 systemd[1]: Finished resolvconf-pull-resolved.service.
Aug 09 21:39:13 kernel: r8169 0000:01:00.0 re0: Link is Up - 100Mbps/Full - flow control off
Aug 09 21:39:13 systemd-networkd[615]: re0: Gained carrier
Aug 09 21:39:17 systemd-networkd[615]: re0: DHCPv4 address 192.168.0.8/24 via 192.168.0.1
Aug 09 21:39:17 systemd-timesyncd[565]: Network configuration changed, trying to establish connection.
Aug 09 21:39:17 systemd[1]: Starting resolvconf-pull-resolved.service...
Aug 09 21:39:17 systemd-timesyncd[565]: Contacted time server 185.125.190.57:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
Aug 09 21:39:17 systemd[1]: resolvconf-pull-resolved.service: Deactivated successfully.
Aug 09 21:39:17 systemd[1]: Finished resolvconf-pull-resolved.service.
Aug 09 21:39:23 kernel: fw-filter: IN=re0 OUT= MAC=00:e0:4c:39:c2:0e:40:61:86:ac:18:81:08:00 SRC=192.168.0.1 DST=192.168.0.8 LEN=88 TOS=0x08 PREC=0x40 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=22 DPT=49754 WINDOW=1027 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0
...

Filtering rules are like this:
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
   27  9435 ACCEPT     0    --  re0    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     6    --  re0    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 22 ctstate NEW
   42  3166 ACCEPT     0    --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 LOGDROP    0    --  !lo    *       127.0.0.0/8          0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 LOGDROP    0    --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID
    0     0 LOGDROP    0    --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 LOGDROP    0    --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID
    0     0 ACCEPT     0    --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     0    --  wlan0  re0     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 LOGDROP    0    --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
   54  5338 ACCEPT     0    --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    5   343 ACCEPT     0    --  *      re0     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW
    0     0 ACCEPT     0    --  *      wlan0   0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW
   21  1271 ACCEPT     0    --  *      lo      0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 LOGDROP    0    --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain LOGDROP (6 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 LOG        0    --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 5/min burst 5 LOG flags 0 level 7 prefix "fw-filter: "
    0     0 DROP       0    --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

How to prevent this issue?
